# How to allow “DateTimePicker” widget in flutter to always be in English while the app supports both languages Arabic and English

Tags: flutter, locale, datetimepicker

I need help regarding the “DateTimePicker” widget in flutter. I am developing a mobile application, this app supports two languages Arabic and English. When the app is in Arabic version the date selected is Arabic date, however English date is specified in the English version. But I want the date to be in English regardless of the language version, because later we need to do a comparison between dates in reports.

I tried to add locale feature inside the “DateTimePicker” widget but it gives some issue. When the app is in Arabic version and the user selects the date, an exception occurs, also some of the widgets inverse to English version directly after selecting the date, however the user is using the Arabic version.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the picker with ```Localizations.override``` ?. Check this out  https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#overriding-the-locale

Comment: This method gave me an exception while using the Arabic version

Comment: What was the exception ?

Comment: The issue below appears when the user select date from DateTimePicker widget. Only if the application in in Arabic language version, but no exception appears in English language version.

E/flutter (14901): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (14901): #0      _DateTimePickerState._showDatePickerDialog (package:date_time_picker/date_time_picker.dart:742:46)
E/flutter (14901): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14901):